# Account pairing analysis from general ledger using pivot in excel

Tags: pivot, accounting

Can anyone advise if it is possible to prepare some sort of account pairing analysis from general ledger using pivots in excel. For example given below very simplified ledger:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhZ9z.png)

To get a matrix like below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awz05.png)

Very simplistic approach is to group on Journal ID level and aggregating on Account names (as columns) but this won't give me matrix like view which would be useful in easier summarisation of account pairings.